# Access, VBA: Find First not working correctly

Tags: vba, ms-access

I hope this is a simple question for someone. I have this method that uses two form fields to check if a record exists in my table and either adds a record or does nothing. So if patient_id is 100, and visit_number is 1, then I will only add a new record if it doesn't already exist.

So, if rst.NoMatch is true - add a new record. However, I can't get it to recognize a duplicate. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub add_record_button_Click()
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Set dbs = CurrentDb


If IsNull(Form.patient_id) Or IsNull(Form.visit_number) = True Then
    MsgBox "Please fill in both fields."
Else
    rst.FindFirst "[patient_id] = " & Form.patient_id & " And [visit_number] = " & Form.visit_number

    If rst.NoMatch Then

        Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("Visits")
        rst.AddNew
        rst!patient_id = Form.patient_id
        rst!visit_number = Form.visit_number
        rst.Update
        MsgBox "New patient visit has been added to the database."
    Else
        MsgBox "That visit already exists."
    End If
    rst.Close
End If
End Sub
```

I believe that my FindFirst line isn't correct. In the database, the variables are named patient_id and visit_number. On the form they are named the same.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT.**

From the comments below, I was able to get my logic working but using a different compare feature, Dlookup.

```
IsNull(DLookup("[patient_id]", "MyTable", "[patient_id] = " & Forms("MyForm").patient_id & " AND [visit_number] = " & Forms("MyForm").visit_number)
```

**FINAL EDIT.**

The above line made everything work if I used the form directly, however if I put the form into a navigation form - it stopped working. The string that ultimately got it working from within a navigation form looks like this:

```
If IsNull(DLookup("[patient_id]", "Visits", "[patient_id] = " & Me!patient_id.Value & " AND [visit_number] = " & Me!visit_number.Value)) = True Then
```

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: is patient_id a numeric field in the DB?

Comment: @A.S.H Yes, I have it set to "Number"

Comment: I failed to find anything wrong with your code. Is your `RecordsetClone` a "table" recordset?

Comment: This is a bit of shot in the dark, but is this a bound form linked to a table? According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194787.aspx) for "table-type" recordsets they recommend using `Seek` instead of `Find`.

Comment: @A.S.H I admit, I don't know the difference. Without RecordsetClone, the page wont work. I only have 1 table for this project, so I believe it to be a table recordset.

Comment: @ChristopherD. Thanks Christopher, I am trying to find a good example of Seek so that I can try this out. This form is linked to a table.

Comment: I'm struggling too. I'm just not familiar with `Seek` and using two criteria makes it a bit more complicated than I can find examples for. Could you use `IsNull(DLookup("[patient_id]", "MyTable", "[patient_id] = " & Forms("MyForm").patient_id & " AND [visit_number] = " & Forms("MyForm").visit_number))` to search for a match instead of `.Find/.Seek` and `.NoMatch`?

Comment: Your code runs just fine on my PC (using a different table, different fields). Are your two form fields textboxes? If you feel like running an experiment, then you can: (1) display your 'FindFirst' search string and look for problems. (2) create a query in the designer, then use your search string for the criteria. Another test would be to add code to open a recordset with a query. Something will turn up.

Comment: What is the Form's recordset SQL string?

Comment: @ThomasInzina I believe this is it: SELECT [Visits].[patient_id], [Visits].[visit_number], [Visits].[visit_date] FROM Visits;

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn Thank you for the ideas, I will start poking around.

Comment: @ChristopherD. Thanks for the idea, I will try that as well.

Comment: @ChristopherD. I used your string from above, and that has the logic working correctly. Thank you for taking the time to look into this. I'll put it in my question in case someone else needs it. Thanks again.

Comment: @ChristopherD. I have a quick follow up question, if you have the time. This works just fine, but when I add it to a navigation pane, it isn't able to find the form. Would I need to change the string to something like Navigation.Forms("MyForm")...?

Comment: "MyForm" is just a placeholder. Replace that with the actual name of your form and it should work. Be careful using form references like Form.Field. That's not explicitly defining your form, just referencing the form object that called the procedure. Use forms ("MyFormName").field or [Forms]![MyFormName]![field] to be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen `Form` used this way, and you should be able to add the record directly in the form, so try:

```
Private Sub add_record_button_Click()

Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone

Dim PatientId As Variant
Dim VisitNumber As Variant

PatientId = Me!patient_id.Value
VisitNumber = Me!visit_number.Value

If IsNull(PatientId) Or IsNull(VisitNumber) Then
    MsgBox "Please fill in both fields."
Else
    rst.FindFirst "[patient_id] = " & PatientId & " And [visit_number] = " & VisitNumber & ""    
    If rst.NoMatch Then
        rst.AddNew
            rst!patient_id.Value = PatientId
            rst!visit_number.Value = VisitNumber
        rst.Update
        MsgBox "New patient visit has been added to the database."
    Else
        MsgBox "That visit already exists."
        Me.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This breaks in an odd way. For the first entry, from when I first open the form, it allows me to enter any option - even though I am entering one that already exist. But then after that, it appear to notice that it is now a duplicate, and wont let me enter it again. And then it also does not let me change the form field without closing and reopening the form.

Comment: Yes, you may have to redesign a little. I believe you have mixed up data entry and data search fields.